# CQWP pass columns by default

Tags: migration, xslt, content-query-web-part

Lately we migrated a website from Sharepoint 2007 to Sharepoint 2010 and one of the issues we faced is that the content query webparts used to work fine but now it doesn't (It's missing some values)

After investigations we found that in the XSL files the client read values from @FileRef
I thought that FileRef is passed by default (I didn't have to add it in CommonViewFields in XSL)

So the only solution we found is to export each webpart and add FileRef in the commonviewfields property in the XSL file which will consume a lot of time

So my question is, Can we pass or send FileRef values by default to all webparts so I don't have to edit every and each webpart ?

In worst case if there's a way to edit multiple webparts CommonViewFields property at once it would be great (batch edit)